# thouse chant is non sum

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english

I am manifold
but called always the same.
With the following told
Do you know my name?

> I have a horny filiation
> I come in rather short notation
>
> You know a pond where I tranquilly float
> I jab you when you shrink or bloat
>
> You feel me when I draw the line
> You smell me when I hold the swine
>
> I firmly wear a mollusk's robe
> Make acronyms around the globe
>
> I keep you locked, with guards about
> Give me a ring, I'll let you out

---

EDIT (Addition): The riddle was answered by puzzledPig (congratulations and thanks).
I posted a complete explantion as a separate reply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edited to explain more lines (thank you to OP and to M Oehm for the hints):

Are you perhaps a

> Pen?

I have a horny filiation

> Pen is derived from the word for feather or quill, which - while not quite a horn - is rather spiky

I come in rather short notation

> Pen itself is a short word

You know a pond where tranquil I float

> A pen is a female swan, which can often be seen floating tranquilly on ponds (though not so tranquil if you get too close, but I suppose that's irrelevant...)

I jab you when you shrink or bloat

> Referring to an EpiPen, which one can jab into one's self for an emergency dose of epinephrine in the case of a severe allergic reaction (which can cause you to bloat).

You feel me when I draw the line

> A pen may be used to draw lines on paper; it would then be felt by the artist as it is used

You smell me when I hold the swine

> A pigpen has a very distinct... er... aroma!

I firmly wear a mollusk's robe

> Pen is the zoological term for the inside shell of a squid

Make acronyms around the globe

> I got a bit of help from Google on this one: apparently PEN is an acronym for the "International Association of Poets, Playwrights, Editors, Essayists, and Novelists."

I keep you locked, with guards about

> A *penitentiary* is another word for a jail

Give me a ring, I'll let you out

> When the letter O (which is in the shape of a ring) is added, we get OPEN; if something (like a door) opens, things are let out

And the title:
thouse chant is non sum

> The first two, at least, are words when pen is appended to the beginning (penthouse, penchant); the third is as well, though less of a family-friendly word.  [According to Google, pennon is a variant of pennant; pensum is also listed as a word, though some sources say it's dated.]

Comment: Eleven lines that form a match - with seven meanings there to catch - It doesn't seem too hard a feat - to have a list of them complete - I would rejoice, could you explain - all those that unmatched yet remain.

Comment: (You nailed it, congratulations and thanks for taking the time. - a hint: the name of the mollusk in question does not contain the letters of the answer.)

Comment: I think the ring in the 10th line is just a letter. And you might find answers to lines 4 and 7 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pen).

Comment: @M Oehm: You think right. And I see it has already found its way into the answer. Your link however provides answers to 3 and 7, 4 is not mentioned there.

Comment: As a ships' dock, I only know this used for submarines, with which I guess something is quite wrong if they are seen floating on a pond :-)  -  I planned to use another line with this one, but then decided that this would actually be about the same meaning as line 6, and I didn't want doubles. - I know that float is not 100% correct, but Oehm's link provides the answer.

Comment: You got #4, Cool!

Comment: I think I got them all now?  Many thanks to M Oehm and to OP, this was fun :)

Comment: Perfect score, you found them all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is:

> Button

because

I have a horny filiation

> buttons could be made from horns

I come in rather short notation

> and they are fairly thin, i.e. short

You know a pond where tranquil I float

> they can float and you can use them as a fishing float

I jab you when you shrink or bloat

> If you change your body size the buttons could cause discomfort

You feel me when I draw the line
You smell me when I hold the swine

> Not sure on this

I firmly wear a mollusk's robe

> Some of them have mother of pearl coating

Make acronyms around the globe

> Not sure about this yet.

I keep you locked, with guards about

> The buttons keep your clothing (guards) about you

Give me a ring, I'll let you out

> But if you push them through the buttonhole (ring shaped) you can undress

Comment: A good approach indeed - 
but not what solves this mess - 
I hope you will succeed - 
with your second guess

Comment: The answer is a better fit - you'll recognize that when you hit

Answer (score 2):

**### Complete explanation ###**

*puzzledPig found the answer. It's*

> pen

*And with a hint from M Oehm they also solved each individual line.*

*But first, the hints that your quick solving abilities prevented:*

Of now there are some hints as follow
I hope that they are neither hollow
nor too revealing of the word
that many times you all have heard.

Hint 1 (about tags):

> You seem to know where we are headed
>  and so another tag was added
>  *(would have added the tag "word", seemed too much a reveal to do that from the start)*

Hint 2 (where to start):

> Some things I hear are best
>  to start right in the middle
>  the same I can attest
>  for our little riddle
>  
>  Allow me to ensure
>  the term is not obscure
>  that solves this little rhyme
>  just try it one more time

Hint 3 (how much to find):

> And once you have the answer right
>  Eleven lines it should fit tight
>  In which you should find seven meanings
>  albeit some but in the gleanings

Hint 4 (specifically for rhsquared):

> You sought the manifold in feature
>  our answer is a different creature
>  as all the *meanings* that it has
>  form its multifariousness

---

*and here are the individual explanations*

The first four lines (on white background) are just the setup of the riddle.
They tell us

> that we look for a single word with many different meanings, and that the point of the ridle is to find that word.

I have a horny filiation

> the etymology of pen goes back to latin "penna" meaning feather, which mainly consists of horn (keratin)

I come in rather short notation

> pen has only three letters, it's a short word

You know a pond where I tranquilly float

> a female swan is called a pen, they are often seen on ponds and are typically described as being more like tranquilly floating than swimming

Have me jab you when you shrink or bloat

> medical injectors for everyday carry are commonly referred to as pens, probably due to their push-button action and pen-like looks setting them apart from a mere syringe. The most widespread seem to be for epinephrine and insulin. Swelling (bloating) is a typical symptom of anaphylaxis, which you counter with epinephrine/adrenaline injections, significant weight loss (shrinking) is a symptom of diabetes, which is treated with insulin injections. - a bit far fetched I admit.

You feel me when I draw the line

> pen is the common abbreviation for pencil, drawing lines is a common application for pens, and it's typically held - and thus felt - in hand while doing so.

You smell me when I hold the swine

> several kinds of animal housing are referred to as a pen, for instance a pigsty, which usually gives off quite an odor.

I firmly wear a mollusk's robe

> the internal horny feather-shaped shell of a squid, holding the outer mantle and many of the muscles, is called a pen

Make acronyms around the globe

> There is a plethora of things all over the world, which the acronym P.E.N. could stand for, I found over 150. The most prominent probably being the one puzzledPig suggested (International Association of Poets, Playwrights, Editors, Essayists, and Novelists), which is all over the world itself.

I keep you locked, with guards about

> pen is colloquial for penitentiary

Give me a ring, I'll let you out

> the ring is the letter "o" which together with "pen" forms the word "open" ;-)

And the title

> is just a collection of syllables that form all proper nouns when prefixed with pen. That was meant as an after the fact confirmation.
>  And I would argue contrary to puzzledPig that the third one is very family friendly, as in most families it played an important role in their foundation.